Is there a way to verify order of HTTP calls?
I am using the Nock library for mocking HTTP calls, with Jest as the testing framework. I am loading mock calls from a json file. Tests work fine, but I want to make sure certain calls happen before others. Is there a way to assert an order? Perhaps viewing the entire call history chronologically or similar?

HTTP Calls are async tasks, so you would need to create a sort of queue mechanism that is based around the question of "Is the previous call resolved?" before making the next API call.

I'm interested to answer this question, but I hesitate to write an answer (especially with any code) because the question lacks a [mre]. (You can [edit] it to include one.)

^ The way that I interpret the question suggests that you can achieve your objective by initializing an empty array before the tests, then append some comparison identifier just before returning each response body inside the callback function for Interceptor.reply… and then compare the identifiers to what's expected at the end. If that answers your question, I can write it as one. If not, what did I miss?
